# how to create a Folder inside a folder in java

Tags: java, json, directory, subdirectory

I have tried to find the path of an existing folder in the same maven project package and create another folder from it.

the existing folder is called client101.userinfo
i have tried to do:

```
File dir = new File("client101.userinfo/userdat");
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use method `mkdirs()`

```
new File("/path/directory").mkdirs();
```

"directory" is the name of the directory you want to create.